# Run two RMI application on a single machine and single IDE

Tags: java, rmi

I've been developing a two applications that communicate with eachother through `RMI`, with one putting data on its local queue and the other one polling the queue for data remotely- Kind of a one-way communication producer-consumer approach. There has been some updates and now I need to make the communication two-way, and that requires using two RMI polling. Apparently I can not run two `start rmiregistry` on a single machine. What shall I do? Is there any workaround for this? I need to run the two applications in parallel on a two different project in Eclipse!

The RMI code for both applications are the same as below. So basically when I run the first one, and then the second one, it throw an exception in the following.

```
try {
            ServerRMI obj = new ServerRMI();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);
            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the exception:

```
Server exception: java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: Hello
java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: Hello
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.bind(RegistryImpl.java:183)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/305254903.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at test.ServerRMI.main(ServerRMI.java:26)
```

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE; it has nothing at all to do with it.  You need two different ports, that's all.

Comment: I know, but don't I need to run two `rmiregistry`? I can't do that. Only one is run at any time!

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072868/viewing-names-bound-to-rmi-registry.html.  Multiple names, each with their own host and port.

Comment: you only need one rmi registry. but you can have as many as you want (subject to resource limitations). it might even be better for each JVM to programmatically start its own registry to host all rmi services of that JVM.

Comment: @bayou.io  I was trying to run the second RMI application, but it throws java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: Hello. Shall I change a port number of something? I updated my question with detailed information.

Comment: OK. I guess I figured it out. Apparently I have to differentiate them by ports using `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int port)`

Comment: How does running two copies of the same code accomplish your objective?

Comment: Because I guess later these two applications might run on two different machines?! I'm very new to RMI though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two RMI Registries. One is sufficient.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with my application right now. I'll play around with it and let's see how it goes...

Comment: I was trying to run the second RMI application, but it throws java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: Hello. Shall I change a port number of something? I updated my question with detailed information.

Comment: OK. I guess I figured it out. Apparently I have to differentiate them by ports using `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int port)`

Comment: ***You don't need two registries.*** I've already said that. You need to use a different bind name for each application.  I recommend using the full name of the remote interface in each case, if that's different, and if it isn't different I don't understand why you want to run wo instances of the same application.